# Removing keyboard on view transition

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to resign the keyboard when user clicks a UIButton, which triggers a new content view (of type UIViewController).

This 'compute' button is at the end of list of several textfield inputs which the user scrolls through for entry; there's no need to resign the keyboard in this view. The scrollview also accommodates resizing when the keyboard is activated.

However, I notice that when proceeding to the next view, upon button click, and then returning to this view of textfields, via the back button on the navigationbar, the keyboard remained up, and this view no longer scrolls the additional area occupied by the keyboard.

My idea is to dismiss the keyboard when the view changes, so when the view returns, any input will trigger keyboard notification and adjust the scroll view accordingly (which is working).

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might get you going in the right direction:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    /*  Dismisses the keyboard whenever the view disappears
     */

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

You could also put that `endEditing` call in the action handler for the "compute" button you mention.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  Unfortunately these lines of code crashed the app.  I put the 2 lines in my -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender, method.  Upon clicking the button, the simulator crashed (went to home screen). I used NO for animated.  My method above instantiates the next view's class (if == nil) and pushes it on the stack:  [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.equationOutputController  animated:YES];

Comment: @Ernest: I forgot the boolean argument at the end. Was it an unrecognized selector exception?

Comment: That solved it.  You're a genius.  Thank you so so so much.  Very much appreciate the help!